# How to avoid automatic pseudo coloring in matplotlib.pyplot imshow()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 28x28 numpy ndarray that I want to print out as an image. Since it is a grayscale picture, it only has one color value per pixel. These values are scaled from -0.5 to 0.5.
I use plt.imshow(array). When I do that, the image gets printed out with the jet colormap, instead of grayscale.

If I apply cmap = 'gray' I get my grayscale image, but why is the default imshow() using the jet colormap)?

Comment: If your question is "why is the default imshow() using the jet colormap?", you should ask it on matplotlib mailing list.

Comment: I thought, that I had something to do with the data format, since, according to the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html),  default coloring is grayscale.

Comment: That's wrong @Fritz Arnold, if you read the docs the default colormap correspond to what is defined by rc image.cmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent matplotlib from using the "jet" colormap as default you need to modify the line corresponding to the default cmap in the matplotlibrc file, usually found in ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc:

```
image.cmap   : gray               # gray | jet etc...
```

Also, I encourage everybody to see the upcoming changes regarding styling in [matplotlib 2.0](http://matplotlib.org/style_changes.html)