# How to show numpy 2d array as grayscale image in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have numpy array with the following properties.

```
np.shape(I)
(300, 300)

np.min(I)
115

np.max(I)
250
```

Unfortunately, when I plot it, I get something greenish bluish.

How to get normal grayscale palette?

[image]

Comment: See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532390/how-to-avoid-automatic-pseudo-coloring-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib
.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(I, cmap='gray')
```